# Make diagonals masks into background-image with only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble making a custom design in CSS. I have all the resources to make it but I don't know why I can't.

I think its easy to anyone who knows a lot of CSS but isn't my case.

I have a 3 div structure in a div parent with flex property. These three containers are 33% of width and when i hover one it expands to the 50% of the screen and the another ones decrease it size. I have that logic made it but my containers have a "background" CSS property inside of the HTML because I'm using drupal and I need to define the image inside HTML. I don't know if its that the key of the error but I've tried with ::before, ::after and cutting manually the images but didn't work.

Desired result:
[image: Result what i want]

My result:
[image: Result i have]

Here its my code

```css
.main-container-paragraph-bannernarrativa {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container1-paragraph-bannernarrativa,
.container2-paragraph-bannernarrativa,
.container3-paragraph-bannernarrativa {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 10;
}

.container1-paragraph-bannernarrativa:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

#content1-paragraph-bannernarrativa {
  opacity: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  margin: auto;
}

#content1-paragraph-bannernarrativa p {
  width: 70%;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#title1-paragraph-bannernarrativa {
  opacity: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.title_custom {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container1-paragraph-bannernarrativa:hover #content1-paragraph-bannernarrativa {
  display: block;
  opacity: 100%;
  z-index: 15;
}

.container1-paragraph-bannernarrativa:hover #title1-paragraph-bannernarrativa {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0%;
  z-index: 0;
}


/*Same for container2 and container3*/
```

```html
<div class="main-container-paragraph-bannernarrativa">
  <div class=" container1-paragraph-bannernarrativa" style="background-image: url({{ content.field_image_1.0['#markup'] }})">
    <div id="title1-paragraph-bannernarrativa">
      <span class="title_custom txt-bold">{{ content.field_title_1 }}</span>
    </div>
    <div id="content1-paragraph-bannernarrativa">
      <h2 class="heading_01 txt-bold">{{ content.field_title_1 }}</h2>
      <p class="subhead">{{ content.field_text_1 }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2-paragraph-bannernarrativa" style="background-image: url({{ content.field_image_2.0['#markup'] }})">

    <div id="title2-paragraph-bannernarrativa">
      <span class="title_custom txt-bold">{{ content.field_title_2 }}</span>
    </div>
    <div id="content2-paragraph-bannernarrativa">
      <h2 class="heading_01 txt-bold">{{ content.field_title_2 }}</h2>
      <p class="subhead">{{ content.field_text_2 }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" container3-paragraph-bannernarrativa" style="background-image: url({{ content.field_image_3.0['#markup'] }})">
    <div id="title3-paragraph-bannernarrativa">
      <span class="title_custom txt-bold">{{ content.field_title_3 }}</span>
    </div>
    <div id="content3-paragraph-bannernarrativa">
      <h2 class="heading_01 txt-bold">{{ content.field_title_3 }}</h2>
      <p class="subhead">{{ content.field_text_3 }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: _'my containers have a "background" CSS property inside of the HTML because I'm using drupal and I need to define the image inside HTML'_ - then I'd start by changing/overwriting that HTML template ... Putting `{{ content.field_image_X.0['#markup'] }}` into `<img src="...">` instead of into `style="background-image: url(...)"`

Comment: This has nothing to do with twig. Please post the actual generated HTML instead of the template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
-webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
-O-transform: skew(-20deg);
```